# Measurable function: inverse of empty set?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(Y,T)$ be measurable spaces, and $f:X\to Y$ be a measurable function. Let $f^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X|f(x)\in A\}$ where , $A\in T$. We know that $f^{-1}(A)\in \Sigma$, but what is $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$, where $\emptyset$ is the empty set? Is it also empty set?

I was asking this because it seems to me that $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$ must be true, while I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: How many $x \in X$ can there be such that $f(x) \in \emptyset$?

Comment: x has to be outside of the domain of f, right?

Comment: Well inside the domain of $f$, there should be no $x$ such that $f(x)\in ∅$..

Comment: Exactly, so $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \in \emptyset\} = \dots$?

Comment: Its the empty set itself. Thanks!